# Receiving new privilege notification before reaching threshold

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, notifications, privileges

I'm getting this notification: "Congrats, you've gained the privilege – talk in chat and 2 other privileges learn more." However, I only have 11 reputation and I cannot talk in chat since this requires 20.

Checking "show removed posts" does not show any downvotes but even if this was the case I would not expect to get the notification. Note that if i remove the notification (click on the X) and click again on my username I get the notification again.

Is this a bug?

Comment: show removed posts won't show downvotes, it will show posts that were removed hence taking away reputation you gained over them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You had [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136500/alternate-for-system-loadlibrary-on-vista/10136668#10136668) accepted then unaccepted...at that point you were at 26 rep, which triggered the privilege notification properly.

We don't remove the notification or provide another "you can no longer do X" when you go down in rep, we assume if something like this happens you'll get back up there soon...or you offered a bounty and are already familiar enough with how the system works.

Comment: Thanks. I'm assuming you can see that it was accepted and unaccepted from somewhere which I can't access, or i'm just not seeing it; either way that's fine.

Comment: @msam The accept-unaccept [happened extremely quickly](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10136500/timeline), so it's hidden from your reputation view. The reason being that outside of showing what triggered the banner, it'd mostly just be noise in cases like this.